# Cordova Inappbroser events not firing

Tags: cordova, reactjs

Please i have a hybrid app that i am trying to deploy to cordova. Recently i am having issue with an Oauth implementation. It force my app to attempt opening a new web browser on Oauth redirect. I then came across InAppBrowser [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)  which i believe should what i want. The problem is, it now display my page with the app like i wanted. However, i dont need the return url . I want to close the inappbrowser once user logged in successfully.

In my onDeviceReady event,i defined my window.open below.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
        app.receivedEvent('root');
 },
```

My app is hybrid build with react. My index.html is like below.

```
<div id="root" class="root app">
    <div class="mobile-page">
        <img class="spinner" src="img/my-symbol-logo.svg" />
        <p class="listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script src="boot.js"></script>
<script async src="app.js"></script>
```

my app.js was build using webpack for my app. My login/authentication page lies in the app.js . It was written in react like .

src/_data.js

```
export const requireAuthOnEnter = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
   const authWindow = window.open(oAuthUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e){ // eslint-disable-line
            alert(e.originalEvent.url);
            authWindow.close();
        });
   authWindow.addEventListener('exit', function(e){ // eslint-disable-line
            alert(e.originalEvent.url);
            authWindow.close();
        });

callback();
}
```

And it is referenced in another class like below.

```
export default [
    { path: '/', component: rootComponent, onEnter: requireAuthOnEnter },
    { path: '*', component: rootComponent, onEnter: requireAuthOnEnter },
];
```

The point is to call `requireAuthOnEnter` on every route . My problem is . The two events from my inAppBrowser does not seem to fire. I want to close the browser as soon as a login is successful. When i put the `.close()` outside the events, it seems to close the window jusst like i wanted . However, i events aren't firing. Please how do i address this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs with `chrome://inspect/#devices`? I think your code inside the `callback` function breaks at `alert(e.originalEvent.url);`.

`e.originalEvent` does not exist so you try to access `url` of `undefined`.

Check the `event` properties of the `InAppBrowserEvent` at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowserevent-properties.

It basically consists of:

- `type`
- `url`
- `code`(for errors)
- `message` (for errors)

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir, I confirm my event get appended to the authWindow. However, The Oauth takes place in a third party site and some how , my authWindow variable seems lost as soon as my Oauth link is accessed.